Not able to get the output which consist all columns of the df after after performing group by on one column
Group the DataFrame by the number of cylinders and find the car with the highest horsepower in each group.
Expected Output:
   Type   mpg  cyl   disp   hp  drat     wt  qsec  vs  am  gear  carb
27   Lotus Europa  30.4    4   95.1  113  3.77  1.513  16.9   1   1     5     2
29   Ferrari Dino  19.7    6  145.0  175  3.62  2.770  15.5   0   1     5     6
30  Maserati Bora  15.0    8  301.0  335  3.54  3.570  14.6   0   1     5     8 

My Output:
cyl
4    113
6    175
8    335
Name: hp, dtype: int64

how should i print the expected output i'm out of ideas...somebody help
**
#This is my code so far**
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("cars_1.csv")

x=df.groupby(['cyl'])['hp'].max()
print(x)


You can use idxmax to get the indices of the required rows, then use these to select the rows: x = df.iloc[df.groupby('cyl')['hp'].idxmax()]
